# Docker container shutting down with logs “SyntaxError: Unexpected token ‘<’”

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, containers, exit-code

So I’m new with docker and I’m running a very simple react app just so I can test my grounds and learn the fundamentals. BUT I’ve been stuck on this error for 2 days now and I would really appreciate some help.

**My docker container exits after run immediately with a syntax error in index.js**

Here is an overview :

- I used create react app and simply added some components
- *Built a docker file this way (this is only the first step of the tutorial I’m following)

  ````
  ```WORKDIR /app

  ```COPY package.json .

  RUN npm install npm

  COPY ./src ./

  EXPOSE 3000

  CMD [“node”, “index.js”]
  ````
- I run my image with this command docker build -t node-app-image .
- I run my container with this command docker run -d -p 3000:3000
  --name node-app node-app-image
- This is my package.json :

[pachage.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN53t.png)

- **THIS IS THE error with docker logs :**

```
    file:///app/index.js:9
    <React.StrictMode>
    ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ‘<’
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:147:18)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:48:21)
```

**- My index.js is really simple I changed nothing**

```
   import React from 'react';
   
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   
   import './index.css';
   
   
   import App from './App';
   
   ReactDOM.render(
   
     <React.StrictMode>
   
       <App />
   
     </React.StrictMode>,
   
     document.getElementById('root')
   
   );
```

- *PS: I’m using ubuntu 20.4

Comment: This is not how you run a react app. Try `npm start`.

Comment: npm start works fine but I'm trying to run in it in my docker container, that's when I got stuck